# SymbolHound: Search Stack Overflow for special characters

Tags: app, obsolete

[image]

### About

See [symbolhound.com](http://symbolhound.com/)

SymbolHound <s>is</s> was a search engine that doesn't ignore special characters. I was always frustrated that I couldn't search for symbols like >> and && using Google or the custom Stack Overflow search, so I made a search engine for programmers. It currently searches mostly Stack Overflow pages, with plans to eventually index a much wider range of programming websites (including symbols, of course).

This is a problem that I know a lot of other Stack Exchange users have run into. It is frequently asked about:

> [MSE: Is it possible to search for punctuation/special characters?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32879/is-it-possible-to-search-for-punctuation-special-characters)
>
> [SO: How can I use a search engine to search for special characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685615/how-can-i-use-a-search-engine-to-search-for-special-characters)
>
> [WebApps: How to search the internet for terms with special characters](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/how-to-search-the-internet-for-terms-with-special-characters)

### Contact

info@symbolhound.com

### Code

It uses the open source [Apache Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/) and [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) for crawling, indexing, and searching, with a small PHP backend for processing user queries.

#### License

Nutch and Solr, which power the backend of SymbolHound, both use the open source Apache license.

Comment: +1 I tried it with some Perl variables (which are impossible to search for with Google, etc.) and I'm pleased to report it worked perfectly.

Comment: this is really great -- and answers at least a few requests on http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Oddly enough, this was not at the top of the list when I search stackapps for "symbol search" haha. I think it was like 10th down.

Comment: Too bad you can't flag a post "Awesome!"

Comment: Fantastic work! Just tried several special character "strings" for different languages and all queries where answered topic-related, whereas Google just displayed junk.. o) Searching for "color-stop()" made Symbolhound stall, though!

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me. The following search: ffmpeg -progress does not find the following SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40216927/ffmpeg-progress-parameter-not-post-ing-any-data

Comment: I have been a regular but not very frequent user for the last few years. It worked for me up until a few days ago. My browser history shows successful visits on March 17 and 25 and April 4. (Before that, in January, in this browser instance.) Did you shut it down, or are you having technical issues?

Comment: I haven't been able to get to symbolhound.com either for a few weeks. I hope it isn't down permanently. It was very useful!

Comment: How frustrating to find something you need, only to discover it's been dead for years…

Comment: @Calion: it hasn't been down/dead for years. It only went down  ~4/2022

Comment: Holy crud! Well, that's irritating…

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is a bug:

[image]

It seems like some of the results for "©" are not from Stack Overflow at all.

Comment: Use advanced search.

Comment: Note: this problem doesn't seem to happen with other symbols (like Perl variables, etc.).

Comment: Though the site does say it searches multiple sites - "SymbolHound searches a growing index of programming websites", maybe there aren't that many posts with the copyright symbol in them.

Comment: Like ChrisF said, this isn't a bug: SymbolHound is expanding to index sites other than Stack Overflow (currently most searches will still give you almost entirely SO pages, though). There is an advanced search feature that allows you to limit searches to specific sites, if you only want to see SO pages.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification. I must have missed reading that part :)

Answer (score 2):

Although Google [claims](https://blog.google/products/search/improvements-searching-special-characters-programming-languages/) to support special characters, it still does not support escape characters.

I tried searching for `\w` with it and found only [three results.](http://symbolhound.com/?q=%5Cw%20in%20cpp%20regex)

Would you please improve this?