# SymbolHound Search

Tags: script, obsolete, search

### Code

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        StackExchange SymbolHound Search
// @description Uses SymbolHound instead of regular search if query begins with "sh:".
// @version     1.1
// @include     http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @include     http://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @include     http://serverfault.com/*
// @include     http://*.serverfault.com/*
// @include     http://superuser.com/*
// @include     http://*.superuser.com/*
// @include     http://stackexchange.com/*
// @include     http://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @include     https://stackapps.com/*
// @include     http://*.stackapps.com/*
// @include     http://askubuntu.com/*
// @include     http://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @include     http://answers.onstartups.com/*
// @include     http://*.answers.onstartups.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

document.getElementById("search").addEventListener("submit", function(event){
    var q = document.getElementById("search")["q"].value;
    if (!RegExp("^sh:").test(q))
        return;
    event.preventDefault();
    document.location = "http://symbolhound.com/?q=" +
        encodeURIComponent(q.substr(3)) +
        "&l=&e=&n=&u=" +
        document.domain;    
});
```

### About

Ever wanted to search for `&&` on Stack Overflow but couldn't? [SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com/) makes it possible!

From their website:

> SymbolHound is a new **search engine that doesn't ignore special characters**. This means you can easily search the web for symbols like &, %, and ^, or even less common characters such as ©, ¬, and µ.

See also: [SymbolHound: Search Stack Overflow for special characters](https://stackapps.com/questions/2690/symbolhound-search-stack-overflow-for-special-characters)

**With this User Script, you can override the built-in search with SymbolHound's.**

Just begin type in your query as usual in the search in the upper right corner, but prefix it with `sh:`.

Examples:

- `sh:&&`
- `sh:php <<<`
- `sh:difference between == and ===`

#### License

I hereby release this script in the public domain.

#### Platform

This user script has been tested in Google Chrome 17.0.963.6 and Mozilla Firefox 8.0 with Greasemonkey 0.9.13.